# Drive API - Save file ID with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, google-drive-api

I´m triying to use Google Drive API quickstart to save **all** files ids with Python.

I want to save files ids in a txt document

This is my code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']



def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    

    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
        archivo = open("Prueba.txt","a")
        archivo.write(item['id'])
        archivo.close()
    
           
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to save all files ids,but my program is not working properly only saves the last file id

What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete from (for items in items:) to (archivo.close())

Then copy and paste this:

```
 for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
            archivo = open("Prueba.txt","a")
            archivo.write(item['id'])
            archivo.close()
```

This should work